# Custom Scheduler - How to delete element inside of JQ-UI "Selectable" element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

New to jQuery here. Love it so far, lots to learn!

Challenge: I cannot delete items inside a recently selected element.

Source: I used the jQuery UI Selectable/Serialize example. Works great, I'm able to select multi divs, insert content.

So far: I've tried assigning class and IDs to new element, but when I click on it, it always re selects the container not delete the element. To make matters worse it will place a new element in the child element.

How to select and delete these "child" spans that are created please? Try it here, select jobs or drag name to job, then try to delete the name you just added.

http://jsbin.com/azeqow/1/edit

(tried to add image of problem, I'm too new)

Comment: When you say "delete", are you saying you press the delete key and want the selected elements to be deleted?

Comment: Yes, I got it working if I remove the UI Selectable..but as long as that feature is active, I can not click on the elements that were dropped.